# Группировка значения при выводе

Tags: mysql

```
id|couple|value
1 |type1 |100
2 |type2 |110
3 |type3 |122
4 |type1 |200
```

Как вывести записи по группам, с их последними значениями? То есть

> type2=100,type3=122,type1=200

Пробовал так, но не работает

```
SELECT * FROM chart group by couple order by id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

так?

```
select t.couple, t.value
from (select max(id) as id, couple from chart group by couple) tg
join chart t on t.id=tg.id
```